# Is there a way in Netty 4 to pass a Channel "Name/ID" on connect that I can use for server-side registration?

Tags: netty, state, channel

**BACKGROUND**:

I wish to maintain a server-side registry of connected Channels, but I also need this registry to be KEY-ed by a well-known name/id - unique per connected Channel.

Therefore, I will be using a string id as the key to each connected Channel - (i.e. both client and server know it, but it will not be a GUID).

When a client connects and the server-side handler's channelActive method is called, I want to pull this Channel **ID** from the ChannelHandlerContext and store this (ID, Channel) pair.

When the channel gets disconnected - either by the client or some failure, I will remove the (ID, Channel) pair from the map.

**QUESTION**:

Is there a way to pass this application data on the client-side Connect call so the server-side handler can read this in it's channelActive method?

Can I do this "on connect" only?   I want to avoid adding this logic into the actual message handling, since this is purely for Channel connect/disconnect identification.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some discussion out-of-band, I understand better that the connect is solely used to establish the physical connection between endpoints.  It's not until the first write on the Channel happens that the various handlers in the pipeline are constructed/used.

As a result, I'm going to build this into our message handling layer - using the client channel's channelActive method to handle making the 1-time registration call.